# How to catch *specific* exceptions in Facebook Business Python SDK?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk

a very simple question, but nonetheless there doesn't appear to be any info on it.

I want to wrap a call to Facebook's Marketing API in a try-except statement. As is good practice (I hear), I want to catch specific exceptions, rather than everything. I know that the main exception I'm dealing with is the **FacebookRequestError**. However, I don't quite understand how i can try-except for this.

If I do...

```
try:
    test = Ad(ad).get_insights()
except FacebookRequestError as e:
    print('Limit exceeded, wait!')
    time.sleep(600)
```

The error-catching doesn't work, because obviously the object 'FacebookRequestError' isn't assigned to anything. I've imported the following at the top of my script:

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount # account-level info
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign # campaign-level info
from facebook_business.adobjects.adset import AdSet # ad-set level info
from facebook_business.adobjects.ad import Ad # ad-level info
```

So, will I need to import the exceptions part specifically in order to catch for them by subsetting a given module I imported for the exceptions attribute? I tried this, but can't find them anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that: `test = Ad(ad).get_insights()` raise the exception in your case ? 
Can you try to accept all exception to see which one is raised if any ?

Comment: sorry -- the exception is thrown once the API limit is reached, not necessarily for that particular call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme in the GitHub repository for that package (which acts as the documentation for the package as far as I can tell) has [a very brief section](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk#exceptions) on exceptions and refers to the `facebook_business.exceptions` module, so that'd be a good place to start.

Comment: many thanks. this fixed it for me:

 
`from facebook_business.exceptions import *`


and then later:
`except FacebookRequestError as e:`